# Sourcetree repository bookmarks disappeared

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Where did my repositories go? They were along the left side of Sourcetree, now it is blank and I don't know how to find them. See the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**version 2.0+**

Bookmarks have changed to local repository folders and are viewed as tabs.

Click the + icon beside the tabs to open a new tab. Your repositories/bookmarks will show up there.

[image]

**before version 2.0**

These are actually "bookmarks" for your repositories that you have lost.

To open them backup, click **View > Show/Hide Bookmarks**, or press **CTRL + B**.

[image]

You might also have just hidden them by accidentally collapsing them to the left. Just drag the bar over, see:

[image]

Comment: What should we do if there is no slider ?

Comment: In version 2 its like https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/How-to-rename-repository-bookmark-in-SourceTree-2-0-19-1/qaq-p/584408

Answer (score 0):

Just as a addition to @Andrew's answer for future readers (like me), the bookmarks bar is back in SourceTree 3.1.1+ (latest is 3.3.8) and you can also group repositories similar to before (possibly [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/bookmarks-column-repository-browser-overview-781398414.html)?).

The sidebar is titled as "Local repositories" and accessible through either `Ctrl+B` or through the menu `View -> Toggle Bookmarks Sidebar`. You can also create folders to group the repositories by either:

- in the right-click menu of the sidebar
- or viewing the local repositories through the "+" button on the right side of the repository tabs and selecting the "New Folder" button at the bottom.

Some more information on the solved issue for it can be viewed here: 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7176